# PHP Specific function variable type declaration

Tags: php, arrays, types, declaration

I'm trying to make a specify instead of `array`, `array(MyClass)`. I want to specify an array of ints, or strings, or a class. On PhpDoc, I would do it like so: `MyClass[]`, but that doesn't work on the function:

```
/**
  * @var MyClass[] $var // works
  **/
function myFunction (MyClass[] $var /* doesn't work */){
    // function does its things
}
```

Another thing I'm interested in is on multiple types. On PhpDoc I would do it like so: `int|string`, but on the function it also doesn't work:

```
/**
  * @var int|string $var // works
  */
function myFunction (int|string $var /* doesn't work */) {
    // function does its things
}
```

How can I make those things.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is (sadly) not supported (yet?) http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: [You](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types) can't [have](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generic-arrays) nice [things](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics).

Comment: See what php 7 offers http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/5-new-features-php-7 what you are asking is still not in the list..